# Compute Adjacency matrix of a graph by it's normalized laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Suppose normalized laplacian matrix of a graph is given. Is there a way to compute or approximate the graph's adjacency matrix ?

Comment: Isn't that just the Laplacian matrix with the diagonal set to $0$?

Comment: Hmm, I thought about it before when I read the graph convolutional operator. However, I doubt it is non-convex problem. Basically, you will need to solve an symmetric binary matrix A, then D is trival. Starting from normalized L, it is extremely hard to solve it. (NP-hard?)